# Get future timestamps

Tags: php

Would it be possible to get the unix timestamp 7 days from now?

Would be awesome!

Comment: http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: Have you given this *any* effort yourself?

Comment: wasnt sure what do google for.. im sorry for wasting db space

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, get the unix timestamp and add 25200 to it.  If you want to format that timestamp you can use date().

```
$future = time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 7);
date("o", future);
```

And from the PHP docs for time()

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 week'))
```

Comment: You also seem to be thinking in the wrong language… "`int future`" :)

Answer (score 6):

**Sure.**

Get the current timestamp. Add 7 days worth of seconds.

Note: *The timestamp "7 days ahead" (in terms of 7 * 86400 seconds) of the current timestamp may not represent the same day-of-week or the same hour in the day* (yay daylight savings!) or even the same second (rare, yay leap-seconds!).

Answer (score 4):

```
time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 7);  // "good enough"
strtotime('+7 days');         // daylight savings save
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add seven days?

```
$future = time() + 60*60*24*7;
//      seconds  ---^  ^ ^  ^ 
//        minutes   ---^ ^  ^
//          hours     ---^  ^      
//            days       ---^
```

See [`time()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php).... oh, the example given there does exactly what you want... I guess you have not read the manual before.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way of doing this on a recent version of PHP is using the DateTime object (in my opinion).

```
$date = new DateTime('now'); // can be anyting else too
$date->modify('+1 week');

// PHP 5.3
$future = $date->getTimeStamp(); 

// PHP 5.2
$future = $date->format('U');
```

Comment: I think that's a bit verbose as opposed to just doing `strtotime('+7 days');` as suggested by deceze and infamouse...

Answer (score 0):

```
$now = time() + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60);
```

Get the current unix timestamp using time() and then multiply 60 seconds, 60 minutes, 24 hours, and 7 days.

Comment: You shouldn't call the variable $now as this is misleading since it is not actually the time now, it's the time 1 week from now.