# how to set timestamp in the future

Tags: php, mysql, variables, time, datetime

I have a question on calculating times.

I have a simple table filled with 3 columns. column 1 will be passed by NOW() in the VALUE. The second column should be the NOW() timestamp plus 14 days. I never used timefunctions before, so I do have some understanding problems.

So is it possible when I have:

```
$copy = "INSERT INTO table (a, b, c) VALUES (NOW(), $var_for_b, $var_for_c)";
```

to use for

```
$var_for_b
```

easily

```
NOW()+14d
```

or do I have to set a variable with a time/date function?

in case of using a variable what can I do there?

```
$in_14_days =mktime(+14d)
```

and my third column should simply be the difference between the NOW() and the NOW(+14d).

I'm sorry for this question but there are so many timefunctions that I do not guess the differences between them.

Comment: Possible duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304578/get-future-timestamps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do `now() + interval 14 day` to set a date in the future.

so your insert statement becomes:

```
$copy = "INSERT INTO table (a, b, c) VALUES (NOW(),now() + interval 14 day, $var_for_c)";
```

Comment: is it that simple like i thought. amazing. and how can i calculate the difference between a and b which will be c? so far thanks to all.

Comment: Yes, it is as easy as that, one can simply do

`$copy = "INSERT INTO table (a, b, c) VALUES (NOW(),now() + interval $var_for_c, $var_for_c)";`

in order to archive the desired result.

Comment: okay and thank you for giving further information. in my case i need to handle $var_for_c later on. thats why $var_for_c not only can be a string like $var_for_c = "14"; this script is related to a loginscript that checks for the difference between a and b. if c will be down to 0 a query will take place. so i think i need a variable for c which exactly calculates the period.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

`NOW() + INTERVAL 14 DAY`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [date_add](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) to have MySQL calculate your timestamp with `date_add(now(), interval 14 day)`

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways one can do this with PHP and MySQL.

I would advise doing it using this method:

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() + INTERVAL 14 DAY)
```

So it will look like this:

```
$copy = "INSERT INTO table (a, b, c) VALUES (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() + INTERVAL 14 DAY), $var_for_b, $var_for_c)";
```

**Alternatively, you can use PHP to do it:**

```
$future = strtotime('+14 days');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try strtotime("+14 day"); and see if that's what you're looking for.

(From the [strtotime() manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) )